# creating php modules load order in centos

Tags: centos, php-fpm, extension

In Debian, we can create order for loading php modules that are installed inside

```
/etc/php5/mods-available
```

By creating symbolic links for php-fpm or php-cli or ...

Could not find something like that in centos!

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Usually load order with symlinks is achieved by prepending numbers to the filename.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should use an extensions.ini that is defining the load order (easier to manage than the content of directories by copy/linking). The order you give in this extensions.ini is used FIFO by PHP itself - https://wiki.php.net/internals/extensions